# Inputting multiple strings and finding their length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the length of elements within a string and return it to the user.

What is the best way of simplifying this code to make the amount of string lengths equate to user input? Also, how can I replace `string1` with the user input, such as "The length of string 'Dog' is 3"?

```
num_of_items = int(input("How many items in your list? "))
def item_list(x):

    items = []
    for i in range(0, x):
        item = input("Enter list %r: " % (i+1))
        items.append(item)
        length_items = ''.join(items)

    return "Itemlist: %r" %(items), "Total length: %s"% len(length_items), \
    "The length of string 1 is %r"%len(items[0]),\
    "The length of string 2 is %r"%len(items[1]),\
    "The length of string 3 is %r"%len(items[2]),\
    "The length of string 4 is %r"%len(items[3])

print(item_list(num_of_items))
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> num_of_items = int(input("How many items in your list? "))
> ```

For one thing, what if the user typed `alpha`?  You would have a nasty error throwing itself at the user.  Why are you asking anyway?  You should be able to handle any number of items without asking.  Just keep asking input and printing output until the user decides to end with `exit`.  Even as it is, your `item_list()` function will print only the first four and if `num_of_items` is, say, three ... IndexError.

> ```
> num_of_items ...
> def item_list(x):
>     ...
> ```

That's a little squooshed.  I would add at least one blank line and probably two between the `num_of_items` definition and the `item_list()` definition.  Well, actually I would put the `num_of_items` definition below the function definition.  Usually, constants are defined first; then functions and classes; then variables.

> ```
> item = input("Enter list %r: " % (i+1))
> ```

`%` formatting is not officially deprecated, but it is preferred to use [.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

I wouldn't create a list of strings whose sole purpose is to be displayed to the user.  There are some things such as `get_accuracy(user)` where you might not use it elsewhere, but it makes sense to use it programmatically.  In this case, you are returning strings that couldn't be read by your program very easily.  Your `item_list()` function should not return strings that are formatted just for the reader.  It should return something that you can format however you like *elsewhere*.  My modified program looks like this:

```
def get_items():
    while True:
        item = input("Enter string: ")
        if item.lower() == "exit":
            raise StopIteration()
        yield item, len(item)

for item in get_items():
    print("The length of string '{0}' is {1}".format(*item))
```

`get_items()` is now a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) function that yields tuples of each item and its length.  Since it raises `StopIteration` when the user types `exit`, the `for` loop will stop.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to comment on your formatting and structure. Generally, definitions are placed first in a file. Seeing it right in between two statements is a bit confusing. I'd also put the newline *before* the `def` line rather than after, after all the indented block is more related to the definition than the preceding line.

On to your questions. There is a cleaner way to include dynamic strings in string literals: using the [`format` method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). This is an example from the documentation:

> ```
> >>> "The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2)
> 'The sum of 1 + 2 is 3'
> ```

Applying this to your code might look like this:

```
"The length of '{0}' is {1}".format(items[0], len(items[0]))
```

Which would yield this, for instance:

> The length of string 'Dog' is 3

Right now, the user has to enter at least four strings, or the program will crash. In addition, if the user enters more strings, only the first four are printed. You could improve your algorithm to handle any number of strings using a second loop, or a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) like below.

```
str_list = ["The length of '{0} is {1}".format(item, len(item)) for item in items]
```

This line creates a list with one entry per element in `items`. The equivalent using a `for` loop would be this:

```
str_list = []
for item in items:
    str_list.append("The length of '{0} is {1}".format(item, len(item))
```